# Динамическое создание переменных в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Скажите, есть ли возможность в JavaScript (и если есть, то как это делать) создавать переменные с разными именами? Имена считываются из DOM-структуры страницы сайта. Мне нужно расположить на яндекс-карте кучу меток:

```
    plasemark_ИмяГорода = new ymaps.Placemark([55.24, 31.71], {
    address: 'Адрес филиала, телефон и фамилия руководителя...',
    link: 'Электронная почта руководителя филиала',
    number: 'номер маркера на карте',
    picture: 'img/map_face_pfoto.jpg',
    iconContent: 'надпись на иконке маркера'
},{
    balloonContentLayout: myBalloonLayout,
    balloonCloseButton: false,
    balloonMinWidth: 513,
    balloonMaxWidth:513,
    balloonMinHeught:251,
    balloonMaxHeught:251,
    iconImageHref: 'img/point.png',
    iconImageSize: [39, 39],
    iconImageOffset: [0, -39],
    iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent'
    
});
```

где "ИмяГорода" - транслитерированное имя города, в котором есть представительство компании. Рядом с картой выводится список городов, при клике на город я хочу центрировать карту на нужном маркере и открывать "Балун" (что такое балун читайте в документации API Яндекс.Карты) текущего маркера с информацие о филиале в городе.  Проблема в том, что открыть таким образом нужный балун можно, если мне известно имя переменной, куда был сохранён объект класса `ymaps.Placemark()`, т.е. как-то так:

```
 plasemark_ИмяГорода.balloon.open();
```

В php есть такая возможность, вы можете задавать динамически имя переменной вот так:

```
${VarName} = value;
```

где `VarName` - строка с именем переменной, удовлетворяющая требованиям PHP к именованию переменных, ну а `value`, соответственно, её значение. Нигде не могу найти информации по реализации подобной возможности в JavaScrit. Может, кто-то сталкивался? Подскажите.

Заранее благодарен!

P.S. Версия API Яндекс карт 2.1, тяну отсюда:

```
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

**Дополнения к вопросу.** (Проблема в том что я не знаю заранее какие города у меня будут, т.е список городов заносит контентщик в админке. Дальше я вытягиваю этот список в DOM документа в виде ul списка с атрибутами и потом в цикле считываю эти атрибуты и создаю на их основе маркеры на яндекс карте.)

Вот HTML список который выводит список городов из админки:

```
<ul class="dsk_regions_list">                                                               
<li map-plasemark="plasemark_46" map-y="39.7241981641" map-x="47.224402114"  map-iconcontent="1" map-picture="/upload/iblock/547/map_face_pfoto.jpg" map-number="1" map-link="ivanov-rostov@donsrtroycom.ru" map-address="ул.Б.Садовоя  №107 Иванов Иван Иванович 8 (863) 268-70-74">
    <a href="plasemark_46" class="js-city">1. г. Ростов-на-Дону</a>
</li>                                                           
<li map-plasemark="plasemark_26" map-y="44.516939" map-x="48.699831222"  map-iconcontent="2" map-picture="/upload/iblock/50f/map_face_pfoto.jpg" map-number="2" map-link="petrov_volgograd@donsrtroycom.ru" map-address="ул. Стечкина д.57 к.3 Петров Иван Петрович 8 (863) 268-70-74 ">
    <a href="plasemark_26" class="js-city">2. г. Волгоград</a>
</li>                                                           
<li map-plasemark="plasemark_27" map-y="38.9852632012" map-x="45.0414049799"  map-iconcontent="3" map-picture="/upload/iblock/242/map_face_pfoto.jpg" map-number="3" map-link="ivanova@donsrtroycom.ru" map-address="пр.Мира д.27 Иванова Мария Ивановна 8 (863) 268-70-74">
    <a href="plasemark_27" class="js-city">3. г. Краснодар</a>
</li>                                                           
<li map-plasemark="plasemark_29" map-y="39.596092291" map-x="52.6068759457"  map-iconcontent="4" map-picture="/upload/iblock/92c/map_face_pfoto.jpg" map-number="4" map-link="kotov@donsrtroycom.ru" map-address="ул. Пушкина д.19 Котов Дмитрий Анатольевич 8 (863) 268-70-74">
    <a href="plasemark_29" class="js-city">4. г. Липецк</a>
</li>                                                           
<li map-plasemark="plasemark_28" map-y="37.6221472168" map-x="55.7522557732"  map-iconcontent="5" map-picture="/upload/iblock/50b/map_face_pfoto.jpg" map-number="5" map-link="sidorov@donsrtroycom.ru" map-address="ул.Ленина д. 159 к.1 Сидоров Сергей Иванович 8 (863) 268-70-74">
    <a href="plasemark_28" class="js-city">5. г. Москва</a>
</li>
```

дальше я обхожу этот список, вытаскиваю нужные мне атрибуты и строю карту с маркерами в JS:

```
    //Создаём коллекцию 
myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();

$(".dsk_regions_list li").each(function(){
    
    var X = (Math.round($(this).attr("map-X") * 100) / 100);
    var Y = (Math.round($(this).attr("map-Y") * 100) / 100);


    
        Placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([X,Y], {
        mapplasemark: $(this).attr("map-plasemark"),
        address: $(this).attr("map-address"),
        link: $(this).attr("map-link"),
        number: $(this).attr("map-number"),
        picture: $(this).attr("map-picture"),
        iconContent: $(this).attr("map-iconcontent"),
    },{
        balloonContentLayout: myBalloonLayout,
        balloonCloseButton: false,
        balloonMinWidth: 513,
        balloonMaxWidth:513,
        balloonMinHeught:251,
        balloonMaxHeught:251,
        iconImageHref: '/bitrix/templates/dsk/img/point.png',
        iconImageSize: [39, 39],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -39],
        iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent'
        
    });
    

    //Добавляем новый маркер к коллекции
    myCollection.add(Placemark);

});
```

Я пытался сделать `Placemark` как пустой объект и потом при создании вот так подставлять `Placemark.$(this).attr("map-plasemark")` где атрибут `map-plasemark` содержит уникальный идентификатор маркера в админке, точнее `plasemark_ИдЭлементаИзАдминки`, но ничего не выходит. Маркеры на карту не добавляются. Всё просто перестаёт работать (пустая карта и всё).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте контейнер для всех `placemark`'ов, и в его свойства пишите отдельные экземпляры:

```
var Places = {}; // пустой объект
Places.Moscow = new ymaps.Placemark( ... );
Places.Peter = new ymaps.Placemark( ... );
// и потом
var city = 'Moscow';
Places[ city]  &&  Places[ city].balloon.open(); // если такой есть, вызвать метод open()
```

Comment: Проблема в том что я не знаю заранее какеи города у меня будут, т.е список городов заносит контентщик в админке. Дальше я вытягиваю этот список в DOM документа в виде ul списка с атрибутами и потом в цикле считываю эти атрибуты и создаю на их основе маркеры на яндекс карте. Посмотрите обновление вопроса, я добавил кода.

Comment: Создавать так же:

    var city = 'Kiev';
    Places[ city] = new ymaps.Placemark( .. );

Не вариант?

Comment: Давно не работал с Яндекс.Картами.. Документацию хорошо читали? У меня две версии сходу: 1. можно ли делать больше одной метки-с-балуном? и 2. в примере кода вы не задаете содержания балуну, а пустой он по умолчанию не показывается, вроде бы.

Comment: Спасибо вот так: var city = 'Kiev'; Places[ city] = new ymaps.Placemark( .. ); всё получилось!